# How to open activities with categoryid

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to create a movie app with RecyclerView. This app include mainly 3 activity. On the first activity movie category eg:Thriller, Drama.. and and the second activity movie image and movie name eg: poster or screenshot, movie details on the third activity. I plan to include 100s of movies in this application. I want to know how to open second / poster activity page of a movie by clicking on the same movie category on the first activity and open detail activity by cliking on the same movie image on the second activity. Please help me...

This is my first activity

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_moviesmain);

    //Actionbar
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.MoviesMain_Toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Movie");
    //set title

    //RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Movies_recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //set layout as LinearLayout
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) );

    //send Query to FirebaseDatabase
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Movie");
}

//load data into recycler view onStart
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MoviesModel, MoviesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MoviesModel, MoviesViewHolder>(
                    MoviesModel.class,
                    R.layout.moviesmainitems,
                    MoviesViewHolder.class,
                    mRef
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder viewHolder, MoviesModel model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getImage());
                }
            };

    //set adapter to recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

This is my First model

```
 String image, title;

//constructor
public MoviesModel(){}

//getter and setters press Alt+Insert


public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;

}
```

This is my First ViewHolder

```
View mView;

public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView = itemView;

    //item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    //item long click
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mClickListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
    });

}

//set details to recycler view moviesmainitems
public void setDetails(Context ctx, String title, String image){
    //Views

    TextView mDetailTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
    ImageView mImageIv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);

    //set data to views

    mDetailTv.setText(title);
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageIv);

}

private MoviesViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

//interface to send callbacks
public interface ClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View  view, int position);
}

public void setOnClickListener(MoviesViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
    mClickListener = clickListener;
}
```

This is my second activity

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_moviessecond);

    //Actionbar
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.MoviesSecond_Toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Movie");
    //set title

    //RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.MoviesSecond_recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //set layout as LinearLayout
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) );

    //send Query to FirebaseDatabase
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Movie");
}

//load data into recycler view onStart
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MoviesSecondModel, MoviesSecondViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MoviesSecondModel, MoviesSecondViewHolder>(
                    MoviesModel.class,
                    R.layout.moviesseconditems,
                    MoviesSecondViewHolder.class,
                    mRef
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MoviesSecondViewHolder viewHolder, MoviesSecondModel model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getImage());
                }
            };

    //set adapter to recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your structure with 3 Activities, the best approach is to add `Listener` in your `Adapter`, something like that:

```
public class MoveiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private OnInteractionListener mListener;

    public MoveiAdapter(OnInteractionListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onFooterClick();
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    public interface OnInteractionListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }
}
```

And you `Activity` will implement this interface `OnInteractionListener` and when `onItemClick()` is called you can open the next `Activity`

Just a suggestion, you can use only one `Activity` and do it with `Fragments`